# Passing props in makeStyles keyframe animations

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

How to pass props fill value to makeStyles' keyframe? Do I have to specify initial states to pass the prop?

It works for the color but does not work for fillvalue.

```
---Child component

const useStyles = makeStyles({
      progress: {
            animation: '$load 3s normal forwards',
            background: props => props.color,
            width: '0',
            },

      "@keyframes load": {
            "0%": { width: "0" },
            "100%": { width: props => props.fillvalue}
            }
});

export default function ProgressBar(props) {
      const propsStyle = {color: props.color, fillvalue: props.fillvalue}
      const classes = useStyles(propsStyle)
      
      return(
            <div>
                  <div className={classes.progress}>
                  </div>
            </div>
      );
}


---Parent

function App() {
  return (
    <div>
      <ProgressBar color="#000" fillvalue = "60%"/>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer to this is - you can't (at least for now). This is a bug as of this writing (MUI latest release is `v4.11.0` as of this writing) and is acknowledged by one of the MUI contributors. You can track its progress at this issue: https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/issues/21011

You are going to have to find other means of passing those props without the use of keyframes

```js
const useStyles = makeStyles({
  progress: {
    height: "10px",
    background: (props) => props.color,
    width: (props) => props.fillvalue,
    transition: "width 3s"
  }
});

function ProgressBar(props) {
  const propsStyle = { color: props.color, fillvalue: props.fillvalue };
  const classes = useStyles(propsStyle);

  return (
    <div>
      <div className={classes.progress}></div>
    </div>
  );
}

function App() {
  const [fill, setFill] = React.useState("0%");

  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={() => setFill("0%")}>0%</button>
      <button onClick={() => setFill("60%")}>60%</button>
      <ProgressBar color="#aaa" fillvalue={fill} />
    </div>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(<App/>,document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<body>
  <div id="root"></div>

  <script src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js"></script>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/babel-standalone@6/babel.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/@material-ui/core@latest/umd/material-ui.development.js"></script>

  <script type="text/babel">
    const { makeStyles } = MaterialUI;
  </script>
</body>
```

Comment: Is there any other way to make it work? I want to reuse ```ProgressBar``` with different fillvalues.

Comment: you may attempt to use `transition` instead like in my example snippet. take a look at that & the arbitrary `width` css property value which is correlated with the `fillValue` prop deeming it as a reusable component

Comment: Here is another example aside from my snippet on my answer which simulates your CSS animation: https://codesandbox.io/s/infallible-river-do0p5?file=/src/index.js

Comment: what do you think about this alternative?https://codesandbox.io/s/happy-sea-nbp60?file=/src/index.js

Comment: you switched to `styled-components`? i think you need to pass down props to `ProgressBar` component https://codesandbox.io/s/festive-paper-pwzxq?file=/src/index.js

Comment: Yeah, I was struggling with that and then I found a way. I gave the props to the max-width and gave 100% in keyframes. Solved my problem. Please checkout that sandbox again. And thank you once again :)         (Not a prect way to do this but at least for now)https://codesandbox.io/s/happy-sea-nbp60?file=/src/index.js

Answer (score 4):

I see that there is no shorter way to do this, so I've discovered a really easy way to pass the props to the @keyframes inside makeStyles You just have
to create a "helper" hook in order to pass the props:

```js
export const useAnimationStyles = ({ width, duration }: Props) => {
  const classes = makeStyles({
    '@keyframes animation': {
      '0%': {
        transform: 'translateX(0px)',
      },
      '100%': {
        transform: `translateX(${width}px)`,
      },
    },
    scroll: {
      animation: `$animation linear infinite`,
      animationDuration: `${duration}s`
    },
  })

  return classes()
}
```

and you can use it as usual:

```js
const classes = useAnimationStyles({width, duration})

...

<div className={classes.scroll}
```